# Como posso criar um DataGridView com MongoDB?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mongodb, mongodb-csharp

Quero apresentar os dados da BD em uma tabela, mas ate agora so consegui faze-lo com recurso a um `ListView`. Como posso fazer isso mas usando um `DataGridView`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;

namespace WFRecibos
{
    public partial class frmListaClientes : Form
    {
        public frmListaClientes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


            public IEnumerable<Cliente> getTodosClientes()
            {

                var colClientes = DbHelper.getCollection("Cliente");

                var clienteLista = from e in colClientes.AsQueryable<Cliente>() select e;

                return clienteLista;
            }

        private void frmListaCli_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var consulta = this.getTodosClientes();
            listView1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (var cli in consulta)
                {
                    listView1.Items.Add(cli.Nome);
                    listView1.Items.Add(cli.Municipio);
                    listView1.Items.Add(cli.Corrego);
                }
        }

        private void gdvClientes_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Você já tem algum código dessa integração com o MongoDB?

Comment: já tem os drivers para C# e tenho a consulta à collection retornando todos os dados do cliente em uma variável 'consulta'.

Comment: @henrique edite sua pergunta e coloque o código que você tem utilizando o `ListView`, isso facilita que outras pessoas possam te ajudar, você poder seguir as dicas [desse link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: inseri meu código... mas hoje consegui listar os nomes das 'colunas' da collection... só que não retornou os dados salvos no DB

Comment: @henrique, respondi a sua pergunta, com relação ao problema que você mencionou nos comentários, crie uma nova pergunta para tentar resolvê-lo, pois creio que esse problema foge do contexto original da sua pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meu problema pode ser resolvido de 2 maneiras.
Segue o código de dois dataGridView cada um apresentando uma solução:

```
private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

        private void frmListaCli_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //-------> gdvClientes   -----------------------------------
            try
            {
                gdvClientes.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

                bindingSource1.DataSource = getTodosClientes();
                gdvClientes.DataSource = bindingSource1;
                gdvClientes.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders;
                gdvClientes.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
                gdvClientes.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("To run this sample replace connection.ConnectionString" +
                    " with a valid connection string to a Northwind" +
                    " database accessible to your system.", "ERROR",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();

            }



            //-------> dataGridView1   -----------------------------------

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Nome");
            dt.Columns.Add("Corrego");
            dt.Columns.Add("Municipio");
            dt.Columns.Add("Ações");

            var consulta = this.getTodosClientes();
            foreach (var cli in consulta)
            {

                dt.Rows.Add(

                             cli.Nome,

                             cli.Corrego,

                             cli.Municipio,
                             "Editar - Excluir"

                             );




            } dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
```

Valew @Mateus Alexandre por ter me ajudado...

Comment: agora você pode aceitar a resposta conforme está no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que o nome da `DataGridView` seja `grdDados`, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
private void frmListaCli_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var consulta = this.getTodosClientes();
    grdDados.DataSource = consulta;

    grdDados.Columns["Municipio"].HeaderText = "Município"; // altera cabeçalho da coluna
    grdDados.Columns["Corrego"].HeaderText = "Córrego"; // altera cabeçalho da coluna
}
```

> **Observação:** coloquei também no código uma opção para alterar o cabeçalho das colunas, você pode usar caso ache necessário.

Caso você queria mais informações sobre a propriedade `DataSource`, você pode dar uma olhada [nesse link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx).

Comment: se eu substituir meu código pelo seu, me dá um dataGridView em branco..

Comment: mas utilizando o `ListView` as informações são exibidas?

Comment: são sim. Ai eu dei uma conferida no link que você passou, e no primeiro exemplo veio minha resposta, testei aqui agora. Agora é descobrir como criar 2 botões para ações de editar e excluir... sou aventureiro em C# trabalho com PHP, ai eu sei o que quero mas não sei como fazer ainda algumas coisas..

Comment: em um teste que realizei aqui com Windows Forms funcionou normalmente, se conseguiu resolver seu problema, responda a sua pergunta falando como fez e o que utilizou, isso pode vir a ajudar outros usuários futuramente